# After update to El Capitan, can't write to my home dir?

Tags: permission, macos, acl

I did a hard drive wipe and clean reinstall for OS X 10.11 El Capitan. I now get some permission errors about my home directory.  Here's an example, after running the program `psql`, which is the PostgreSQL command line interface.

```
could not save history to file "/Users/rob/.psql_history": Permission denied
```

If I look at my home dir, the `rwx` part looks right, but there is an extra ACL. Should I delete that ACL? Why is it there? Lots of programs write to `.` files in home directory.

```
$ ls -lde /Users/rob/
drwxr-xr-x@ 27 rob  staff  918 Oct 22 16:31 /Users/rob/
0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
```

Comment: What are permissions on the file?

Comment: There is no file. I think the error is when it can't create it.